# JavaScript function length and arguments properties/fields

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to js although years of experience with Java

I suppose when I declare a function,it is essentially a special type of object,and got some builtin fields that are accessible directly such as "arguments" and "length"

I notice I can access something like "arguments" inside the scope of a function
i.e.

```
function add(a,b) {
    return arguments[0]+arguments[1]
}
```

Also I can access something like "length" outside the scope

```
//2
alert(add.length)
```

the above snippet should be the right way to use

however

```
function sum(a,b) {
    // error
    return length
}

// null
alert(sum.arguments)
```

I suppose arguments and length are not of the same basic, is it right idea?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

After some research,I got the root cause of the confusion.
The issue revolves around property VS variable in JavaScript

Property belong to Object while Variable belong to Context.
The two ideas can be interchangeable sometimes: 
The global context happen to be window

```
<script>
   //property
   window.foo="a"
   //variable
   var bar="b"
   //a
   alert(foo)
   //b
   alert(bar)
</script>
```

In most scenario,say,function context,they are completely different ideas,partly because you can never access the function object in your code.Thus,contrary to a global setting ,assign a property is impossible! What is possible is just declare a variable in scope

In my question
   "arguments" is a variable
   while "length" is a property
I failed to distinguish the two

For more information,please refer to 
[this post](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/)

Comment: This function declaration is not valid javascript . I guess you should see [arguments doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: @Hacketo: Not sure what you're talking about unless you mean the very last line of code. The first two function declarations are valid. (They'd both likely fail when called, the first because of the missing `s` on `arguments`, the second because there's probably no in-scope `length` variable, but...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder are you talking about that one `function sum(a,b,){` ? because this throw syntax error

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just a typo，arguments I mean

Comment: @Hacketo: Ah, missed that extra `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, length and arguments are different concepts.

Contrary to Java, where fields (attributes) of your object, methods, and local variables are all accessible in the same scope (just via an identifier), JavaScript does distinguish heavily between scope variables (with closures, lexically referenced) and object properties (possibly inherited) - not only in concept, but also in syntax. Properties are always<sup>1</sup> accessed via `.` or `[]` notation.

The [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) of `Function` instances is such a property. You will always have to write `add.length` or `sum.length` (or `…["length"]`). If you just use `length` inside of the function, it doesn't automatically refer to the property - it's a variable reference, in this case to an undeclared one.

The [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in contrast works like a variable. It cannot be accessed as a property of the function<sup>2</sup>. Admittedly, it's a bit special, because you cannot see the declaration of the variable - it is created implicitly in every function scope. It works a bit as if there was a `const arguments = {0: a, 1: b};` statement in the first line of the function.

<sub>1: Not exactly true, there's a [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) that explicitly lifts object properties into a scope. It's despised due to its ambiguity and deprecated in strict mode though.

2: There also is a deprecated [`.arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) property on functions, accessing it on strict mode functions throws. If not accessed during the invocation, it's `null`.</sub>

Comment: thanks,you got me! you understand my confusion revolves around the differences of the two !

Comment: I suppose "length" is a common concept of a function(because function is an object,and length is a property),while "arguments" is special ,it is something like implicit object (such as session,context) in a JSP page,which is managed by container(maybe interpreter in js setting)

Comment: Yeah, `arguments` is special, but more like a form of reified reflection. It's not a global session or context of a JSP page, but created by every function call - like `this` is.

Comment: I happen to view a reallyyyyyyyy awesome blog to clarify the issue!!!!    [link](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/)

Comment: @user2670585: Yeah, nice one, especially detailing the global object's behavior - there's always an exception to the rule :-) I did omit it from my answer for simplicity. But don't forget that the "*VariableObject*" he talks of is only an implementation detail, and similar wordings in the spec only describe the expected behaviour - an actual implementation might look totally different.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are objects in JavaScript. Proper, real objects.

#### `length`

The `length` property of a function is the number of *declared* arguments it has (this is also called the "arity" of the function). The arity (`length`) of `add` is two because you declared two formal arguments for it: `a` and `b`.

#### `arguments`

The `arguments` pseudo-array is not part of the function object. It's an object created when the function is called, and only in scope within that function call's context. It contains all of the arguments that the function was *actually* called with, which can be different from the number of arguments it declares. Each separate call to the function gets its own separate `arguments` object.

In JavaScript's "loose mode" (the only mode it had before 2009's ECMAScript 5th edition specification), there's a live connection between the `arguments` pseudo-array and the declared arguments:

```
// In loose mode only
function foo(a) {
   console.log("a = " + a);
   console.log("arguments[0] = " + arguments[0]);
   a = 42;
   console.log("a = " + a);
   console.log("arguments[0] = " + arguments[0]);
}
foo(67);
```

In loose mode, that outputs:

```
a = 67
arguments[0] = 67
a = 42
arguments[0] = 42
```

In "strict" mode (which is the preferred mode to use), that link doesn't exist (we'd see `arguments[0] = 67` at the end), which is useful for JavaScript engines for optimization purposes.

Comment: it seem length is like a traditional field of a class,just like a field in Java class,On the other hand,where is arguments from?

Comment: @user2670585: `length` is a *property* of an *object*, not a field of a class. (JavaScript doesn't have classes in the Java sense.) `arguments` comes from the process of calling the function; it's just a built-in thing, a bit like how in Java you magically have `this` and `super` in instance methods.